# My favorite Lord of The Rings character

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, wordplay

If -

> Halo is 0.5
> Soy is cunning
> Pot is a dab
> Rio is free
> Oil is 0
> Lost is an ultimate
> Bio is substantial

Then,

***My favorite Lord of The Rings character is ?***

Answer (score 26, accepted):

> Let's replace the right sides with synonyms that match the left side when one letter is replaced by the One Ring - er, I mean an 'O':

> Halo is 0.5 - halo is halF.
>  Soy is cunning - soy is sLy.
>  Pot is a dab - pot is pAt.
>  Rio is free - rio is riD.
>  Oil is 0 - oil is Nil.
>  Lost is an ultimate - lost is lAst.
>  Bio is substantial - bio is biG.

> The letters replaced by O are FLADNAG...
>  Which, backwards, reads GANDALF! A great character indeed.

> * cleaned up this post per notes by op, tech, and IIC.

Comment: Great Job! Also, Rot13(B'f jrer pubfra orpnhfr gurl ybbxf yvxr Evatf :))